# Increment Value of Row in SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have one table `Metal_Master` in that column having `Opening_Weight` I am updating value of that column by fetching previous value and aadding some value then again update that value .

My code for this is

```
ConnectionDB ReturnMWeight = new ConnectionDB("SELECT Opening_Weight FROM Metal_Master WHERE Metal_Name='GOLD';");
DataTable weighttd = ReturnMWeight.returntable();
GoldW = GoldW + Convert.ToDouble(weighttd.Rows[0][0].ToString());
ConnectionDB AddMWeight = new ConnectionDB("UPDATE Metal_Master SET Opening_Weight=" + GoldW + " WHERE Metal_Name='GOLD';");
AddMWeight.AddData();
```

But i want to directly update value in single query Please help ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do the `UPDATE` directly without running select statement,

```
UPDATE Metal_Master 
SET Opening_Weight = Opening_Weight + new_Value
WHERE Metal_Name='GOLD'
```

for better quality of code,

- use `using` statement for proper objet disposal
- use `try-catch` for proper handling of unexpected exceptions.
- parameterized the query to prevent from `sql injection`

Comment: *follow-up question: What is `ConnectionDB`?*

Comment: ConnectionDB is class for my Database related function

Answer (score 2):

You can use the column name in right side of set.

```
 ConnectionDB AddMWeight = new 
 ConnectionDB("UPDATE Metal_Master SET Opening_Weight = Opening_Weight " +  10 + " WHERE Metal_Name='GOLD';");
```

Comment: Thanks @JW. you are right, updated my answer, I hope it would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ConnectionDB AddMWeight = new ConnectionDB("UPDATE Metal_Master SET Opening_Weight=(SELECT SUM(Opening_Weight) AS Opening_Weight FROM Metal_master WHERE Metal_Name = 'GOLD')" + GoldW + " WHERE Metal_Name='GOLD';");
AddMWeight.AddData();
```